# UDP Socket writes expired packets when Ethernet is reconnected. How do I flush the write buffer from the socket when Ethernet is disconnected?

Tags: sockets, udp, winsock, ethernet

I have a "Transmit Thread" that manages a socket (#include WinSock2.h) for transmitting all the UDP data my application requires. The application is a c++ Windows app running on Windows 10. I am sending up to 5 or so packets per second to a subnet broadcast address, each packet less than 200 bytes.

The problem is, when I disconnect the Ethernet, there seems to be some un-sent data in the write buffer of the socket than I haven't been able to flush out.

When my application detects the ethernet loss, I close (closesocket) and re-open the socket. Immediately upon re-connection, the socket sends several old messages that were "sent" around when the Ethernet was disconnected.

I think this problem is outside my application. I have disconnected ethernet while the application is running and then closed the application. Immediately upon re-connection, I see that several of the messages get transmitted, despite the application no longer running.

Things I have tried (without luck):

I have tried calling `shutdown( m_sock, SD_BOTH );` immediately before `closesocket( m_sock );`

I tried writing a buffer full of zeroes to the socket immediately before closing

I can't set the `SO_DONTLINGER` option because my socket is `SOCK_DGRAM`

When I try `WSAIoctl( m_sock, SIO_FLUSH, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesRead, &wsol, NULL )` it returns error 997 (WSA_IO_PENDING)

I don't know how to stop the IO from pending.

Neither `WSASendDisconnect( m_sock, NULL )` nor `CancelIo( (HANDLE)m_sock )` work, and neither signals error

Comment: You don't have any control over how the OS buffers outgoing packets. Once you put a packet into the kernel's buffer, it is out of your hands. And FYI, networks are designed to be resilient to momentary outages, hence why outgoing packets are not discarded right away when the network connection is lost, and why they get resent upon re-connecting. It takes awhile for an outage to truly take effect. All you can really do is detect the network disconnect (Windows has API callbacks for that) so you can stop sending packets as soon as possible, but you can't flush out what you have already "sent".

Comment: Is there a setting for the NIC that may help address this?

Comment: not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with my software, or with my local NIC, as far as I can tell. My NIC was connected to an Ethernet hub before connecting to other devices on my LAN via a Switch.

The presence of the hub caused the described behavior. Without the hub, I don't experience any "flush" or sending expired packets.